# Javascript function is not being called in Laravel app

Tags: javascript, laravel

So I was following this tutorial on Youtube :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OCbdZnrE4Fc

The code ran fine while he was doing it but I got stuck with an issue with the same code. What he did was create a "manage.js" file in the resources/js folder containing the following code :

```
const accordions = document.getElementsByClassName('has-submenu');

function setSubmenuStyles (submenu, maxHeight, margins) {
    submenu.style.maxHeight = maxHeight;
    submenu.style.marginTop = margins;
    submenu.style.marginBottom = margins;
}

for (var i=0; i<accordions.length; i++) {
    accordions[i].onclick = function () {
        this.classList.toggle('is-active');

        const submenu = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (submenu.style.maxHeight) {
            // menu is open, we need to close it now
            setSubmenuStyles(submenu, null, null);
        } else {
            // meny is close, so we need to open it
            setSubmenuStyles(submenu, submenu.scrollHeight + "px", "0.75em");
        }



    }
}
```

Then he called this file from the resources/js/app.js file by adding the following line of code:

```
require(./manage)
```

In his code, it worked just fine with the above two steps and I got stuck. I did npm run dev. I checked the compiled app.js file in the public folder and I can see the functions there. When I checked the browser console and checked the variable and the function it says **"uncaught reference error"** for both the variable accordions and the function setSubmenuStyles. I have found a workaround to this problem by copying the script to my layout file and it works.

But I want to find out why it is not working as it should in the tutorial. I am out of my wits. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: can  you make sure that your file is actually required 
put a console.log or a breakpoint

Comment: I just checked in both files (app.js and manage.js) and console.log shows both entries.

Comment: maybe he/she was using a different and older version of laravel. try adding your js files in your mix file.

Comment: what's your laravel version `php artisan --version`

Comment: my laravel version is 5.7.13. I am sure his laravel version is older than mine. The question is how do I do it in the latest version? I am quite new to laravel.